# Facebook posts to users wall, pictures appearing twice

Tags: facebook, posts

From an iPhone app, I am making a post to the users Facebook wall. Post shows up in timeline twice, the first with a (Globe) indicator and the second with the Friends indicators. The timing is the same time or very occasionally a second apart. Why is this happening and how do I eliminate this?

Comment: What's your posting code doing?